# Batch Script to copy base64 encoded image to new text file

Tags: batch-file

I have a large number of .xml files that each contain multiple base64 encoded .png images. I have been coping the encoded data out and manually creating a new file for each image. Then decoding the image, renaming it and adding the .png file extensions using a .bat script. I would like to have the script read the file and find the encoded string then copy to a new file for each image. First, I cant get that to work. Second, in some of the .xml files the encoded data is separated on different lines. So the script cant just copy the line after finding a string. IDK...Im at a loss for what to try next. I would post some of the nonsense I've tried but that would be pointless, so please excuse that.

But here is an example of what I would want to copy to a new file...

```
<Image Height="140.0" Left="0.0" Name="dog" Top="0.0" Width="131.0"><![CDATA[EncodedImageExistsHere]]></Image>
```

If possible I would like to only grab that is between CDATA[]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=3delims=[]" %%a IN (q26521345.txt) DO (
 ECHO found %%a
 SET "found=%%a"
)
ECHO process found %found%

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q26521345.txt` containing your data for my testing.